# Generating a JSON-Array and converting it to a Base64-String

Tags: arrays, json, swift, base64

I'm trying to create a Base64-String in Swift. I have an example of a Base64-encoded string and its array-counterpart. My problem now is, that I don't know how I get an equivalent array to the one which is given in the example.

Because I didn't want to mess around in my XCode-project I did the following in a playground.

given array:

```
{"WHERE":{"Class":"%3f","Location":"3b"},"ORDER":["Day ASC","Location DESC"]}
```

given Base64-string:

```
eyJXSEVSRSI6eyJDbGFzcyI6IiUzZiIsIkxvY2F0aW9uIjoiM2IifSwiT1JERVIiOlsiRGF5IEFTQyIsIkxvY2F0aW9uIERFU0MiXX0=
```

First I'm decoding the example-string

```
let str = "eyJXSEVSRSI6eyJDbGFzcyI6IiUzZiIsIkxvY2F0aW9uIjoiM2IifSwiT1JERVIiOlsiRGF5IEFTQyIsIkxvY2F0aW9uIERFU0MiXX0="

let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: str, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

do {
    let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
//"result" is ["WHERE": ["Class": "%3f", "Location": "3b"], "ORDER": ["Day ASC", "Location DESC"]]
```

Below I'm trying to reproduce the string from above

```
var array = [String : AnyObject]()
var arrayPartA = [String : String]()
arrayPartA["Class"] = "%3f"
arrayPartA["Location"] = "3b"
array["ORDER"] = ["Day ASC", "Location DESC"]
array["WHERE"] = arrayPartA
array //The playground says that "array" is ["ORDER": ["Day ASC", "Location DESC"], "WHERE": ["Class": "%3f", "Location": "3b"]]
      //"ORDER" and "WHERE" are switched but I don't get them to be at the right position

let utf8str2: NSData = String(array).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

let encodedStr = utf8str2.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
//Here "encodedStr" is WyJPUkRFUiI6ICgKICAgICJEYXkgQVNDIiwKICAgICJMb2NhdGlvbiBERVNDIgopLCAiV0hFUkUiOiB7CiAgICBDbGFzcyA9ICIlM2YiOwogICAgTG9jYXRpb24gPSAzYjsKfV0=
//but it should be eyJXSEVSRSI6eyJDbGFzcyI6IiUzZiIsIkxvY2F0aW9uIjoiM2IifSwiT1JERVIiOlsiRGF5IEFTQyIsIkxvY2F0aW9uIERFU0MiXX0=
```

I would be glad if someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how I can reproduce the given Base64-string.

Since I'm new to this website I apologize in advance for wrong layout or other possible conventions I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Could you try this please? Is this what you wanted to do? It should convert a Dictionary to base64 String

```
func jsonToBaseString (yourJSON: [String: String]) -> String? {
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: yourJSON, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        return
            jsonData.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithCarriageReturn)
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Dictionary is Swifts JSON representation...

Answer (score 1):

Two important things to understand:

- What you are calling an array is not an array, it's a JSON dictionary (containing an array for the ORDER key).

Be careful not to confuse the syntax of arrays and dictionaries between Swift and JSON.

In Swift, an array: `[0, 1]`, a dictionary: `["a":0, "b":1]`.

In JSON, an array: `[0, 1]`, a dictionary: `{"a":0, "b":1}`.

- A Swift dictionary is an *unordered* collection. There's no "position" for key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change several things:

1. Your input string (not serialized) is not an array, but a JSON object.
2. Try constructing your string with a proper JSON library, such as [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).
3. `String(array)` is not enough to consistently convert your objects to strings. You should use a JSON serializer (such as SwiftyJSON `json.rawString()`).

Answer (score 0):

let follow recommendation to use some json serialization, but take in account that

```
{
    "alfa": 1,
    "beta": true
}
```

and

```
{"beta":true,"alfa":1}
```

represents in JSON notation the same object even though their string representation  ( doesn't matter if base64 encoded or not ) are different.